# Directional derivative in orthogonal directions of a determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-analysis, svd, orthogonal-matrices

I am trying to calculate the gradient $\nabla_\theta f \big|_{\theta_0}$ of the following function
$$f(\theta) = \frac{1}{2} \text{log} \det \left( Q^T(\theta) J^T(\theta) J(\theta) Q(\theta) \right)$$
where
$$
f:\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R};~~~~~Q:\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^{d \times (d-t)} (!!!);~~~~~J:\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^{d \times d},
$$
and $t < d$.  One important detail that I am trying to leverage is that $Q(\theta)$ is the compact SVD of a projection matrix $P(\theta)$ such that the columns of $Q$ are the orthonormal eigenvectors of $P(\theta)$ associated with the non-zero eigenvalues.

I would *very much* like this calculation to sidestep a direct differential of $Q(\theta)$, since I do not think that the "function" (!!!) above is even a function since the compact SVD is non-unique.  In that direction, I am considering the directional derivatives

$$
\nabla_\theta f = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
D_{q_1} f & \cdots & D_{q_d} f
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
Q^T(\theta_0) \\\ 
Q_\perp^T (\theta_0)
\end{pmatrix},
$$

where $q_i \in \begin{pmatrix} 
Q(\theta_0) & 
Q_\perp (\theta_0)
\end{pmatrix}$ are the columns of the "completed" $d \times d$ orthogonal matrix.  My intuition is that $D_{q_i} f = 0$ whenever $q_i \in Q_\perp(\theta_0)$ (please excuse the abuse of the $\in$ notation).  That is, going in the direction orthogonal to all columns in $Q(\theta_0)$ should yield no change in $f$.

Any thoughts or suggested readings would be appreciated.  I've tried a lot of (incorrect) ways to prove my conjecture.